# Playing an audio file with NodeJs on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, npm, raspberry-pi

I am trying to play a audio file from a raspberry pi with a NODE server running. But I want the output sound on the client side (the website).
I tried a solution with NPM audio-play and audio-loader but it didn't worked for me.

```
server.get('/api/audio', (req, res) => {
    load('public/resources/alarm.mp3').then(play);
    console.log("Alarm is playing!");
    res.send("Success");
});
```

and I also get this error when starting the server

> `speaker` package was not found. Using `audio-sink` instead

is this the wrong approach for my problem does anyone know a more fitting module?

Answer (score 1):

html5 has a native support for playing audio files

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="alarm.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

if your server responds to the client request with an audio file, you can dynamically create the above `audio` tag.

Comment: That was my first attempt but I always get a: "Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission" if I try with the play() mehtod

Comment: Alright it is because of the Safari browser blocking all audio autoplay so everything that is not caused by a clear user event. In my case I got a button that starts a timer and when the timer passed there should be an alarm ringing.